# Initialize data structure's field in Rust with another data structure

Tags: data-structures, rust, move-semantics

I have recently started to program in Rust and would like now to create a structure, which fields I would like to assign using other structures. In the code base, which I am working with, there is the following example:

```
pub struct StType1 {
    f1: String,
    f2: bool,
    f3: usize,
}

pub struct StType2 {
    // ...
    field1: StType1,
    // ...
}

impl StType2 {

    // ...

    pub fn build(mut self) {

        // ...

        let st = StType3 {
            field1: self.field1,
        };

        // ...

    }


    pub fn field1(&self) -> &StType1 {
        &self.field1
    }
}

struct StType3 {

   field1: StType1,
   // ...

}
```

**StType1** is the type of the field, which is contained in both structures **StType2** and **StType3**. **StType2** while running **build()** function creates **StType3** and they should have the same value of **field1**.

In this code there is no move and seems no copy in this assignment `field1: self.field1;`. Why? What happens then?

I am asking because when I try to create a similar to **StType3** - **ObjType** - structure outside this file:

```
let object1 = StType2::new(...);
let object2 = ObjType {
            field1: object1.field1().clone(),
}
```

within my functions, I get a reference to StType1 after **clone()**, not an object, and when I am doing this:

```
let object1 = StType2::new(...);
let object2 = ObjType {
            field1: *object1.field1().clone(),
}
```

I get an error `Can't move`:

> move occurs because value has type
> `StType1`, which does
> not implement the `Copy` trait

I solve it by adding to the **StType1** `#[derive(Clone)]`. But it worked before with **StType2** without `#[derive(Clone)]`. Why should I add it now? Why there was no move happenning (or no clone required) for **field1** when this **StType3** was created inside **StType2** and the **field1** was initialized?

Comment: I think you've reduced the example a bit too much. What are `StType1` etc supposed to represent? And what are the arguments to `build`?

Comment: @LambdaFairy, thanks for the comment. There were just too many other details and function calls in the code, which I tried to eliminate to leave the core idea. Hope now it is a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this code there is no move and seems no copy in this assignment `field1: self.field1`. Why? What happens then?

This is incorrect – there *is* a move here, because Rust moves by default.

And this is possible because in the declaration above:

```
pub fn build(mut self) {
```

there is no `&` before the `self`, and so this `build` method takes `self` by-move.

In contrast, the method below:

```
pub fn field1(&self) -> &StType1 {
    &self.field1
}
```

takes `&self`, i.e. a reference, and returns `&StType1`, another reference. So to get a `StType1` to construct your object, you need to make it owned by calling `.clone()`. But that will only work if `StType1` implements `Clone`, which is why you had to add `#[derive(Clone)]` to it.

Alternatively, you can change the `field1()` method to take `self` by-move as well:

```
pub fn field1(self) -> StType1 {
    self.field1
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that since it consumes `self`, i.e. the entire struct, you won't be able to access any of the other fields after it's called.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! My bad that I didn't check through the project if this self.field1 is accessed anywhere else. But seems yes, StType2 just loses it after the move, maybe not a clever decision... Anyway, thanks a lot again.